# Finding a potential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> $F(x,y)= \left(\displaystyle\frac{1-y^2}{(1+xy)^2},\displaystyle\frac{1-x^2}{(1+xy)^2}\right)$.

I've been having some troubles to find the potential of $F$.

To find it the idea was finding $\int F dx = g(x,y) +h(y)$, and having $g$ find the function $h$. Unless my calculations have a mistake, this doesn't seem to work.

$$\int Fdx = \int \frac{1-y^2}{(1+xy)^2} dx = (1-y^2)\int \frac{1}{(1+xy)^2}dx\\
= (1-y^2)\left(\frac{-1}{y(1+xy)}+h(y)\right)\\=h(y)-y^2h(y)+\frac{y}{(1+xy)}-\frac{1}{y(1+xy)}.$$

Now I'd have to find the $\partial y$ of the latter equation, and find $h(y)$, but

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(h(y)-y^2h(y)+\frac{y}{(1+xy)}-\frac{1}{(1+xy)}\right)\\=h'(y)-2yh(y)-y^2h'(y)+\frac{1}{(1+xy)^2}+\frac{1+2xy}{y^2(1+xy)^2}\\=\frac{y^2+2xy+1}{y^2(1+xy)^2}+h'(y)(1-y^2)+2yh(y).$$

Then I must solve the follwing for $h$

$$\frac{y^2+2xy+1}{y^2(1+xy)^2}+h'(y)(1-y^2)+2yh(y)=\displaystyle\frac{1-x^2}{(1+xy)^2}\\ \frac{x^2y^2+2xy+1}{y^2(1+xy)^2}+h'(y)(1-y^2)+2yh(y)=0.$$

This is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to solve for $h$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier if you add the $y$-dependent function *after* taking a primitive of (the first component of) $F$:
$$
\int \frac{1-y^2}{(1+xy)^2}\,dx=\frac{y^2-1}{y(1+xy)}+g(y).
$$
Then differentiate with respect to $y$.

(You could also see this as renaming *your* $h$, like $g=(1-y^2)h$.)

Now, it should be possible to solve this as you do anyways. On your last line, you should cancel $(x^2y^2+2xy+1)$ with $(1+xy)^2$ to find that
$$
\frac{1}{y^2}+h'(y)(1-y^2)+2yh(y)=0,
$$
or equivalently, with $g$ in place of $h$,
$$
\frac{1}{y^2}+g'(y)=0.
$$
I'm sure you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

You're over thinking it. Just do this:

$$ \int F dx = -\frac{1-y^2}{y(1+xy)} + h(y)$$

Since $1-y^2$ is just a function of $y$ anyway, it gets absorbed in the second function.